# Исполнение NSTimer в цикле

Tags: xcode, objective-c, iphone

Уважаемые знатоки, я использовал совет из другого треда, взятого здесь, но появилась проблема в которой не могу разобраться, в чем суть:
Задача: Сделать чтоб поочередно помигали две картинки, сначала одна, потом другая (смена изображений), реализовано вот в таком коде:

```
static int count = 0;
........
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

      _forBlink = i;

        // здесь вызывается визуализация мигания
               [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.1
                                         target: self
                                       selector: @selector(blink:)
                                       userInfo: NULL
                                        repeats: YES];
    }
```

Метод где собственно осуществляется "мигание":

```
- (void)blink:(NSTimer *)timer
{

if ( (count % 2 ) == 0 ){ // четное
     UIImageView *Pic = [self valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Pic%i", _forBlink]];
     Pic.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"];
 } else {
     UIImageView *Pic = [self valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Pic%i", _forBlink]];
     Pic.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"];
 }

if (++count == 18) {
     // Как только действие повторилось
     // 16 раз — уничтожаем таймер
     [timer invalidate];
     timer = nil;
     count = 0;
 }
}
```

Что получается в результате выполнения - если в цикле оставить одну итерацию (мигание одной картинки), то все проходит нормально, если делать как указано выше (с двумя картинками поочереди) , то отрисовывается (моргает) только вторая картинка, первую как будто проскакивает и она остается без изменений.

Может у NSTimer при использовании в цикле есть нюансы?

Answer (score 1):

Вот как бы я накидал для ответа на данный вопрос:

```
//
// Created by Maksim Bunkow on 25.02.14.
// Copyright (c) 2014 TradeAndChat. All rights reserved.
//

#import "TestViewController.h"

@interface TestViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *imageView1;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *imageView2;
@end

@implementation TestViewController
{
    BOOL isChanged;
    BOOL isChanged2;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _imageView1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"]];
    [_imageView1 setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
    [_imageView1 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width/2, self.view.bounds.size.height/2)];
    [self.view addSubview:self.imageView1];

    _imageView2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image3.png"]];
    [_imageView2 setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
    [_imageView2 setFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width/2, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width/2, self.view.bounds.size.height/2)];
    [self.view addSubview:self.imageView2];
    [self p_startAnimationImage1];
}

- (void)p_startAnimationImage1
{

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{
        [_imageView1 setAlpha:0];
    }                completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if (isChanged)
        {
            [_imageView1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"]];
        }
        else
        {
            [_imageView1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"]];
        }
        isChanged = !isChanged;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{
            [_imageView1 setAlpha:1];
        }                completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [self p_startAnimationImage2];
        }];
    }];
}

- (void)p_startAnimationImage2
{

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{
        [_imageView2 setAlpha:0];
    }                completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if (isChanged2)
        {
            [_imageView2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image3.png"]];
        }
        else
        {
            [_imageView2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image4.png"]];
        }
        isChanged2 = !isChanged2;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{
            [_imageView2 setAlpha:1];
        }                completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [self p_startAnimationImage1];
        }];
    }];
}

@end
```

[Сорц](http://cl.ly/0s3q080G0F2n)

Comment: Спасибо за человеческий ответ. Но это я так понимаю для одной картинки. С одной картинкой у меня и тимер и очередь работает, не работает с двумя-тремя и т.д. когда они должны "моргать" по очереди.
или здесь в дидлоад-е [self p_startAnimation] поставить в цикл и передавать ему имя картинки которую менять нужно? Что-то кажется мне что визуально ничего не отработает.

Comment: :( неужели пример не наводит на нужные мысли?

Comment: Обновил код, с вас 100 баксов ;)

Comment: Честно говоря устал уже от "наводящих" ответов. И вы сами, и еще один участник в данной ситуации(предыдущие треды) настойчиво рекомендовали использовать NSQueue. Я разобрал метод по косточкам, а оказывается он так работать не будет?
Я ж вроде конкретный вопрос задаю, а в ответ получаю одни намеки :(
PS Я на Ob-C недавно перешел, пытаюсь его понять.

Comment: Именно наводящие ответы, заставляют учиться. Здесь вам не аутесресы сидят и работу за вас делают, это тоже нужно понимать. А то что вы спросили можно реализовать туевой хучей способов. Я для примера опубликовал ответ, по вашей задаче, как я ее понял. Ваша задача выкурить как это работает прочитать документацию поучиться как это все прикрутить. Дерзайте.

Comment: NSQueue, а точнее NSOperationQueue очень мощьный инструмент для многопоточного программирования, не поленитесь изучите.

Comment: Максим спасибо большое за развернутый ответ. Но здесь наверно я сам виноват - сформулировал задачу не совсем верно. Я не буду углубляться в новое описание т.к. не хватит символов в комментариях. 
Скажу просто - вы должны понять, в том числе почему не подходит этот код.
Картинок для "моргания" может быть от 1-й до 8-ми, само действо происходит в FVC, при срабатывании определенного условия вызывается через сегвей SVC и ему передаются номера картинок которые должны "моргать" (все 8 картинок уже есть в SVC). Поэтому я все и запихал в цикл, а количество итераций = количеству картинок.

Comment: И мой вопрос был если честно не - "как это реализовать?" , а почему не правильно работает в указанном примере NSQueue, точнее почему работает не так как я хочу - из двух-трех-четырех и т.д. картинок моргает всегда только последняя, те кто перед ней - без изменений.
Точно так же отрабатывает и NSTimer.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите в сторону NSOperation и NSOperationQueue

Comment: Пробовал:
operationQueue = [NSOperationQueue new];
NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                          selector:@selector(blink)
                                                                          object:nil];
[operationQueue addOperation:operation];
 и в 
- (void)blink
{
for (int i = 0; i < 18; i++) {
if ( (i % 2 ) == 0 ){ Pic0.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"];}
else {Pic0.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"];}
[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.0f];
}

Картинки не меняются((

Comment: Разобрался с очередью, я сам неправильный селектор поставил. С одной картинкой заработало.
[Pic performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setImage:) withObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"] waitUntilDone:YES];

Но если два NSQueue запускается в цикле один за другим (две картинки), то отображается мигание одной как в сабже, вторая не изменяется ((